# Можно ли запустить c++ программу на Android без Java?

Tags: android, c++, native

Есть ли способ собрать программу для андроида на c/c++, в котором не будет Java-кода? Если да, то кто будет запускать процесс программы? Это сделает ВМ Dalvik? Можно ли обойтись без ВМ для запуска?

Например, для простой консольной программы, которая напечатает строку "Hello Wolrd!" в std::cout.

Comment: Есть замечательный [Termux](https://termux.com/). Еще некоторые C/C++-библиотеки для работы с графикой поставляются с маленькой java-прослойкой для запуска плюсового кода.

Comment: А можно примеров таких библиотек-прослоек? И вопрос про Termux - это получается отдельное приложение, внутри которого можно запускать свои бинарники? Или я не так понял?

Comment: *"отдельное приложение, внутри которого можно запускать свои бинарники"* По сути да, но сами бинарники настоящие линуксовые. Он даже убунту в chroot-е может запустить (но для графики нужны какие-то хитрые маневры). *"примеров таких библиотек-прослоек"* SDL2 точно, GLFW не помню.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете скомпилировать свои программы C с помощью кросс-компилятора ARM:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv7-a test.c -o test
```

Затем вы можете поместить свой скомпилированный двоичный файл куда-нибудь (не вставляйте его на карту SD..

Comment: Спасибо. А почему не стоит использовать SD-карту?

Comment: Да, буду пробовать. Плюс поставил, но он не увеличивается/не отображается, т.к. система пишет, что у меня не достаточная репутация (<15), но он учитывается